# Scipy Optimize Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have a dataframe like so:

`ID | size | p1 | p2 | ... |p10| quantity | o1| o2|...|o10|`

p1 to p10 and o1 to o10 are float32 values. Size is a string. For one ID there can be 1 or more sizes. For every size there is one row p1..p10 but only 1 row of o1..o10 for every ID whether it contains 1 or more sizes.
I have 10 linear equations like so:

```
f1 = [(p1S1*qS1)+(p1S2*qS2)+...+(p1Sn*qSn)] + o1
f2 = [(p2S1*qS1)+(p2S2*qS2)+...+(p2Sn*qSn)] + o2
.
.
f10 = [(p10S1*qS1)+(p10S2*qS2)+...+(p10Sn*qSn)] + o10
```

Where p1S1 is p1 of size 1, qSn : quantity of size 1. Bounds for q are either -q<solution<0 or 0<solution<q depending on whether q is negative or positive.

I want to solve for q in order to maximize (C is constant):
`F = max(C, f1, f2,...,f10)`

I've looked into the documentation of scipy.optimize.minimize but I don't fully understand how to pass data in. Please help!

Comment: Something like `minimize(F, C0, args=(f1,f2,f3...))` may work.  Keep in mind that `scipy` uses `numpy`, so your code may work better if you use the dataframe/Series `values` directly.

Comment: When I try to pass Pandas series directly I get an error: Series object is not callable